# Google Login broken on website

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I just tried to ask a question, but I cannot sign in with my Google account. I'm using the Android app since I'm already logged in there.

When I click the sign in button, nothing happens. I'm using Windows 10 and I tried it with Firefox 64.0 and Chrome 71.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`currentPage` ended up not being correctly scoped in the JS there. Sorry about that, a fix is rolling out ASAP.

Thanks for the report!